# singular value decomposition of a matrix over a field K

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, finite-fields

Can I do singular value decomposition of a matrix which has entries from a field K, in my case $Z_m$, in Mathematica? For example, I have a matrix over a field Z2, with entries only 0 and 1. Using an inbuilt function, I can get the rank of the matrix modulo 2 in this case but I couldn't find inverse or how to do singular value decomposition.

Comment: Is SVD well defined in that setting?

Comment: For the inverse use `LinearSolve[A,IdentityMatrix[Length[A]],Modulus->m]` or `Inverse[A, Modulus->m]`.